# Find a thumbnail to display for any user-defined link?

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook-graph-api, thumbnails, meta-tags

When you copy a link into a WhatsApp conversation, a thumbnail image and a few lines of the targeted page are shown. And when you post a link on Facebook - same thing.

How do they always find a thumbnail image to display, for any kind of link? So long as the target page at all has an image on it!

I would like to do the same in my Flutter app. I've already managed to show a YouTube thumbnail like this:

```dart
import 'package:youtube_parser/youtube_parser.dart' as yt;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<String> getFutureYoutubeThumbnailUrl(String userDefinedLink) async {
  String? thumbnailUrl;
  String? videoId = yt.getIdFromUrl(userDefinedLink);
  if (videoId != null) {
    http.Response? res;
    try {
      res = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=$videoId&key=$googleApiKey&part=snippet'));
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error getting YouTube snippet: $e');
    }
    if (res != null) {
      print('res.body is ${res.body}');
      Map<String, dynamic> decodedResponse = jsonDecode(res.body);
      thumbnailUrl = decodedResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'];
    }
  }
  print('thumbnailUrl is $thumbnailUrl');
  return thumbnailUrl ?? '';
}
```

Then I display the URL once it's ready as: `Image(image: NetworkImage(thumbnailUrl))`.

But this requires very specific knowledge about where to find the thumbnail URL in the response from the very specific YouTube API call!... What if I don't even know whether it is a YouTube link or some other type of link? Do I need one tailored solution for each type of link I can think of? Is that how Facebook and WhatsApp do it?

Isn't there some convenient plug-and-play solution for this, that can be found online, or something?

---

Follow-up qn:

Now, you've tipped me of a flutter package, which is great. But I was wondering: Is there a more generic, language independent solution for doing this, too? Like with an API call? And if so, how would I write this API call?

Comment: Use this https://pub.dev/packages/any_link_preview

Comment: Awesome!  Seems like exactly what I'm looking for! Why don't you post this as an Answer though, rather than a comment? Comments can be cleared away at any time, according to StackOverflow documentation.

Comment: Also, is there a more generic, language independent solution for doing this, too? Like with an API call? And if so, how would I write this API call?

Answer (score 2):

First of all the explanation on the example Facebook. Most of the social networks are providing these kind of informations with Facebook meta tags.

The keys for the Facebook image are for example:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" /
```

Other platforms are using this the same way, since its really important for all kind of websites at the moment they are having a blog and or are using SEO. So its something typical.

Now for the usage in flutter you don't have to care about the source somebody is sharing basically. You just need a placeholder if there is no image provided from the source. Using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/any_link_preview) package for example

```
You can run this example and try it out on yourself:

import 'package:any_link_preview/any_link_preview.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  /// I picked these links & images from internet
  final String _errorImage =
      "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/z8wrRRR7_qU/maxresdefault.jpg";
  final String _url1 =
      "https://www.espn.in/football/soccer-transfers/story/4163866/transfer-talk-lionel-messi-tells-barcelona-hes-more-likely-to-leave-then-stay";
  final String _url2 =
      "https://speakerdeck.com/themsaid/the-power-of-laravel-queues";
  final String _url3 =
      "https://twitter.com/laravelphp/status/1222535498880692225";
  final String _url4 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1pNjxmNHNQ";
  final String _url5 = "https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/motivational-quotes";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getMetadata(_url5);
  }

  void _getMetadata(String url) async {
    bool _isValid = _getUrlValid(url);
    if (_isValid) {
      Metadata? _metadata = await AnyLinkPreview.getMetadata(
        link: url,
        cache: Duration(days: 7),
        proxyUrl: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/", // Needed for web app
      );
      debugPrint(_metadata?.title);
      debugPrint(_metadata?.desc);
    } else {
      debugPrint("URL is not valid");
    }
  }

  bool _getUrlValid(String url) {
    bool _isUrlValid = AnyLinkPreview.isValidLink(
      url,
      protocols: ['http', 'https'],
      hostWhitelist: ['https://youtube.com/'],
      hostBlacklist: ['https://facebook.com/'],
    );
    return _isUrlValid;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Any Link Preview')),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              AnyLinkPreview(
                link: _url1,
                displayDirection: UIDirection.uiDirectionHorizontal,
                cache: Duration(hours: 1),
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                errorWidget: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                  child: Text('Oops!'),
                ),
                errorImage: _errorImage,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 25),
              AnyLinkPreview(
                link: _url2,
                displayDirection: UIDirection.uiDirectionHorizontal,
                showMultimedia: false,
                bodyMaxLines: 5,
                bodyTextOverflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                titleStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 15,
                ),
                bodyStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 25),
              AnyLinkPreview(
                displayDirection: UIDirection.uiDirectionHorizontal,
                link: _url3,
                errorBody: 'Show my custom error body',
                errorTitle: 'Next one is youtube link, error title',
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 25),
              AnyLinkPreview(link: _url4),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

From the docs your are also able to generate a custom placeholder if there is no image to provide.

> Placeholder which can be used while the state is in loading.

This is what I mean. Every important technology to receive those image sources are provided here. HTML parser for all kind of websites, opengraph twitter for all the big social media platforms.

> HTML Parser, JSON LD Parser, Open Graph Parser, Twitter Cards Parser
> and more coming up in the future.

Comment: Thanks! But if I don't want to use the package, how would I use that first information you wrote, from the Facebook docs, to find a thumbnail? Like with an API call.

Comment: You could check how it is solved in the package but tbh why wouldn’t you use the library which does all the boilerplate for you? The meta tags are provided in the html of the posts from the www.

Comment: Yes, I know I can try and found out how the package does it, and tbh, I don't need you to qn my motives for me!  But if you must know, I was thinking this qn and answer could be more useful for other developers not using Flutter if there were a generic method.  Plus, if it's easy to do it manually, it may be less cumbersome than using the package. Plus I just like to learn...

Comment: alright, then it would make sense that you accept the answer and if you like to you can upvote, so it will be provided for other users if they search for it. ill also add another tag on your question so it has more attention

Comment: ...I meant: The answer with the MORE GENERIC way would be more useful than the Flutter specific way you've provided... This was in response to your qn "Why wouldn't you use the library?" I wouldn't use the library because I think a more generic, language independent way would be more useful. If you don't have a more generic way, it's ok! I'll just wait a bit to see if somebody else does, and if not, I guess I will accept your answer.